# JSF Boolean CheckBox in Lazy DataGrid - primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have Primefaces' lazy datagrid with paginator. I want to add a boolean checkbox for each of my record to provide multiple selection.

As I don't know how many records there are I can't define their value in managed bean. How can I define and manage these boolean checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can learn how to do it directly from this PrimeFaces showCase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml (see the last example).